# How to access div id from next page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="common_script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <h1>My First Page</h1>
        <p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="common_script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My second Page</h1>
        <div id="nextpageId">I want to access my div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**common_script.js**

```
function init() {
    alert($("#nextpageId").text());
}
```

In the following code I have two pages i.e. `page1.html` & `page2.html` and these contain the common JavaScript file.

My problem is to access `page2.html` `div#id` when `page1.html` is loading.

Comment: Though modern phones can do many things, this is impossible. There's no way to catch a page and an element in it from a server just with plain `id`.

Comment: why would you want to do that? http is stateless, if you want to retain state from one page to another, you need to use cookies and/or manage the state server side.

Comment: Ok,thanks.how i solve my problem using jquery mobile.login page is page1.html and listview page is page2.html

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. Presumably Your login page will have a "login" button with a form containing user id and password that you validate server side. If  login is valid, you send page 2 html back to the browser

Comment: actually i have build the application using phonegap.I create the database with two tables i.e;login table and listvie table.When the app is first loading database is created.index.html page is first loading when the user click the submit button it goes to listview page.Problem is index.html is first loading i need get the id from the listview page.But id is not getting.Is any way to solve my problem...thanks.

Comment: please use url for this purpose

Comment: please include page2.html in page1.html and then access div text

Comment: Thanks,But i need to reload the page when it goes to page2.html

Answer (score 0):

use this in your javascript

```
$('body').attr('unique_id')
```

and give unique id for your page in body tag

```
<body id='unique_id'>
```

or you can also pass in url

or use this code

```
function init() {
    alert( $('div').attr('id') == "nextpageId" )
}
```

Comment: Thanks please give me one example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explicitly state that you are using jQuery Mobile but you have tagged your question as such and are using PhoneGap so I will assume so...

Your pages don't conform to a standard jQuery Mobile layout. They are missing the required `data-role`s. Specifically `data-role="page"` along with child `data-role="content"` declarations.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Your second page will be loaded via Ajax and the `<script>` tag on the second page will be ignored. In fact, only the contents of the nested `<div data-role="page">` section will be loaded.

To pull that markup, you can simply access the `<div>` given its ID and that ID should be unique. You can use the `pageinit` or `pageshow` events to control your timing on the Ajax load.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html